# How can I make one child window draw over another within the same form?

Tags: c++, winapi, z-order

Let's say I have ten child windows within a form. How do I make sure one of those windows is drawn over all the others? For example, how do I make sure that window 6 always overdraws windows 1-5 and 7-10?

I don't want the window to be drawn over everything else on the screen, just everything else within that form. I've already tried using HWND_TOPMOST and HWND_TOP (see [How can I make a child window topmost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823700/how-can-i-make-a-child-window-topmost) ) but it didn't work. :(

Comment: I've seen this before, it's probably a bug (i.e., you have the right idea but you're doing it wrong). Can you post a little code?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545%28VS.85%29.aspx), it can change z order of child windows